# Why is volume inversely proportional to pressure?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, gas-laws, gas-phase-chemistry

If temprature is directly proportional to volume (Charles's law) and
temperature is directly proportional to pressure (Gay-Lussac's law), then why is pressure and volume are inversely proportional?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given you know and understand Charles' and Gay-Lussac's laws, it's not about chemistry, rather, [simple ratios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportionality_(mathematics)):

$$
\begin{cases}
T \propto V\\
T \propto p
\end{cases}
\implies
p \propto \frac 1 V
$$

which, as Zenix commented, is a math form of [Boyle's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyle%27s_law).